# How should 'Quit', 'Save Draft', and 'Continue' be positioned on mobile web?

Tags: mobile, buttons, placement

Note: Due to the constraints of this project, I can only touch the CSS. Basically, we're being hacky and styling this desktop site so that it's halfway usable on mobile.

I'm working on a web app where users must answer some questions, then continue to the next page. They also have the option leaving the question process but saving their place (Save Draft) or just leaving the process without saving their place (Quit).

Given that the primary action is 'Continue', I'm suggesting it be full-width and a prominent color. 'Safe Draft' and 'Quit' would be placed either above or below it, and that's where my question comes in.

I think it makes more sense to put 'Save Draft' and 'Quit' above, as I believe that would prevent fat fingering when trying to hit 'Continue'. The other designer says to put 'Save Draft' and 'Quit' below continue, given that as a primary action, it should come first. Is there a best practice when laying out these actions, or are there any insights you guys may have?

[image: Options]

Comment: Does "save draft" quit immediatly? Because that might be a bigger problem than the layout (two actions behind one button). You could also have "Quit" and "Continue" only. A click on "Quit" will automatically save for later. When the user starts the app again, you could ask if he likes to start from the last saved question or start all new.

Comment: This question might also help a little bit http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/44787/how-can-i-indicate-that-a-required-field-is-only-required-for-final-submission/ (not saying it's a duplicate)

Comment: @DonL. Both 'Quit' and 'Save Draft' (which is more like save and quit) ask for confirmation. We're working with a database that's already in place, though, so while I like your suggestion, we can't implement it.

Comment: If you are asking for confirmation anyway, maybe just remove the "save" and add a third option to the "quit" confirmation

Comment: All we can do is style it, it's a really messed up project. We're basically taking the output of a CMS and slapping some  CSS on it. We can move things around and change how it looks and that's about it :-(

Comment: I feel sorry for you, bro. I had to do these kinds of projects, too.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your question, to clarify that you can only apply css

Answer (score 2):

What I propose is this:

[image]

- "Save Draft" functionality (saving the progress of user) could easily be replicated when user clicks on "Continue" and hence there is apparently no need for a separate "Save Draft" button.
- "Save and Quit" can be used by user when he wants to leave in the middle but also wants to save the progress. There will be no confirmation dialog box when user clicks on it.
- "Exit" button is self descriptive and tells the user that he can exit this whole thing by clicking here and as such he wouldn't be expecting the software to save his progress. 
   Here, you could have a confirmation dialog box asking user for his willingness to exit the application and not save the progress. It could say "Do you want to save the progress? Yes or No". If user clicks on "No", he exits without saving and if he clicks "Yes", he will exit while saving the progress much like the functionality of the button "Save and Quit".

Comment: Is it ok that `continue` saves without the user's knowledge? Will they become confused about whether their data is saved?

Answer (score 1):

A few insights on your design:

- You are placing a `Quit` button in a close proximity to the `Continue` button - meaning some may hit it by mistake. Specifically as `Continue` is the prime business goal. I would move the quit to be a small X icon on the top of the page. Also bear in mind that for forgiveness sake, you should offer a cancel option after quit is pressed.
- With both `Quit` and `Save Draft` the users would not wish to continue. So you can compact these two action into one, simply called `Quit` (or the X icon on top), when the user clicks it, offer:

  - **Delete Draft** (delete is better than just quit as it signifies some loss of work may be involved).
  - **Save Draft**.
  - **Cancel** (in case someone clicked `Quit` by mistake).

This how the mail app on the iPhone deals with the delete request:

[image: A Screen Shot of the menu showing after you press delete in the iphone mail application]

Answer (score 0):

How many questions do users have to answer? If it's just a handful of them, and they're not too complex, maybe saving a draft isn't that necessary.

Could they just click/tap on the answer and proceed automatically to the next question? That would allow you to have the back at the top left (as iOS usually has it) if they want to change it. That way you'd only have 2 buttons to worry about: "Cancel" and "Save Draft" (if my previous question hasn't discarded that already).

Could you have a "Next" and a "Previous" question buttons and save the session automatically with every "next"?